# How can I create all combinations of links?

Tags: r

I have three combinations:

```
10 20 30 40

ab bc cd da

clim dlim alim blim
```

And one url:

```
www.climdata.com
```

Basically, I want to create a list of all 3 combinations with the url that I can use curl on to download the files:

```
www.climdata.com/10abclim.zip
www.climdata.com/10abdlim.zip
www.climdata.com/10abalim.zip
www.climdata.com/10abblim.zip
www.climdata.com/20abclim.zip
www.climdata.com/20abdlim.zip
www.climdata.com/20abalim.zip
www.climdata.com/20abblim.zip
www.climdata.com/10bcclim.zip
www.climdata.com/10bcdlim.zip
www.climdata.com/10bcalim.zip
www.climdata.com/10bcblim.zip
```

etc.

Comment: Can you make your data reproducible? It is not clear how the combinations are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` with `paste`

```
paste0(do.call(paste0, expand.grid(list(paste0(link1, "/"), v1, v2, v3))), ".zip")
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
v2 <- c('ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'da')
v3 <- c('clim', 'dlim', 'alim', 'blim')
link1 <- 'www.climdata.com'
```